# Error syntax error, unexpected token "use"

Tags: php, api, session, woocommerce

Estoy utilizadon la api de WooCommerce para listar productos cuando el usuario este dentro de su cuenta. Pero tengo este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "use" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sync\index.php on line 19

Y ocurre cuando el usuario cierra la session y luego no puede volver a ingresar. Comente donde esta linea `19` y cuando quito el condicional `if($_SESSION)` me deja ingresar y no tengo problemas con esa linea. Es el condicional el que esta mal? Como lo puedo solucionar?

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$sistema = new Sistema();

if($_SESSION){

$user = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$usuario = $sistema->usuario($user);
$id = $usuario['id']; // ID del usuario


// WooCommerce
$woo = $sistema->wooUsuario($id); // Clase Sistema, funcion wooUsuario(un parametro)
require __DIR__ . './librerias/woocommerce/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client; // linea 19

$woocommerce = new Client(
    $woo['url'],
    $woo['wookey'],
    $woo['woosecret'],
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3'
    ]
);

} else{
    echo 'El usuario salio del sistema';
}

?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como dicen en su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):

> Reglas de ámbito para la importación
>
> La palabra reservada use debe ser declarada en el ámbito exterior de
> un fichero (el ámbito global) o dentro de declaraciones de espacios de
> nombres. Esto es así debido a que la importación se realiza durante la
> compilación y no durante la ejecución, por lo que no puede ser
> utilizada en un ámbito de bloque.

De ahí el problema. Sácala del condicional y que sea de ámbito global y esquivarás ese error.